# Where can we find noises like Gaussian, Rayleigh, Gamma, exponential noises in real world images?

Tags: noise

I know that while taking pictures from a camera, noise may appear in the image.
It is often described as  Gaussian, but what about the other noises, when do they occur in real world?

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gaussian Noise: Standard model of amplifier noise.

Gamma Noise: Frequent in Radar/LiDAR.

Rayleigh Noise: One example where the Rayleigh distribution naturally arises is when wind velocity is analyzed into its orthogonal 2-dimensional vector components.

Exponential Noise: Channel Based Communication(see AEN).

Comment: [Salt and pepper noise is definitely NOT Gaussian.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise#Salt-and-pepper_noise)

Answer (score 3):

The noise that appears on x-ray images is Poisson in nature.  I find the treatment in [Computed Tomography: From Photon Statistics to Modern Cone-Beam CT](http://books.google.co.nz/books/about/Computed_Tomography.html?id=fNH1fSnjwrkC&redir_esc=y) to be good for showing why, but in summary: X-ray photon generation in an x-ray tube is a Poisson process, then attenuation in whatever is being imaged is binomial, and so is detection, so the final image is still Poisson.

I can't help with examples of the other types, sorry.